# How to remove HTML, Urls from with Python

Tags: python, html, regex, xml, text-classification

I have this list of xml files. Now I have to filter some labels out of it. The problem is the text, there is a lot of html mark up and urls in it and I need plain text. I would like to remove this elements in a loop and then append the cleaned text to my new list. This is what I have so far.

```
    data = []
    for conv in root.findall('./conversations/conversation'):
        pattern = re.compile( r'!\b(((ht|f)tp(s?))\://)?(www.|[a-z].)[a-z0-9\-\.]+\.)(\:[0-9]+)*(/($|[a-z0-9\.\,\;\?\\\\\\\+&amp;%\$#\=~_\-]+))*\b!i')
        if pattern.search(conv.text):
           re.sub(pattern, ' ')
           data.append(conv.text)
```

I can't find the right regex to remove things like this `br />;<br />` and urls like this: `http://neocash43.blog.com/2011/07/26/psp-sport-assessment-neopets-the-wand-of-wishing/</a>`

Second problem is that with this xml root structure, I don't now how to append the cleaned conversation text to my new list.

Comment: Can you please provide an expected input-output example?

Comment: I would suggest looking into beautifulsoup4, "a Python library for pulling data out of HTML and XML files. It works with your favorite parser to provide idiomatic ways of navigating, searching, and modifying the parse tree."

Comment: Are you confident of that URL? When I try to load it I get a 502 Bad Gateway. For my clarification, do you want to remove all of the HTML tags from a string that you have recovered from some xml?

Comment: @BillBell I'm so sorry, The Url was an example of an url I want to remove

Comment: @Szalbolcs Input text: '\n\t\t\tZafaras really have the finest hearing out of any other pet in Neopia.<br />;<br />;If you haven&#146t heard of Neopets than I have to significantly wonder what planet you arrive from, you surely don&#146t hail from Neopia. <a href="http://en.pan.netcom/go/out/url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.neopets.com"target="_blank" rel="nofollow">,       Output: Zafaras really have the finest hearing out of any other pet in Neopia.If you havent heard of Neopets than I have to significantly wonder what planet you arrive from, you surely dont hail from Neopia.

Comment: My mistake! Misread your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/file/view/htmlStripper.py/591745692/htmlStripper.py which uses the pyparsing library. I just used this script on my machine with Python 3.4.

Comment: Pyparsing is no longer hosted on wikispaces.com. Go to https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing

Answer (score 0):

[pattern.web](http://www.clips.ua.ac.be/pages/pattern-web) python modules has an HTML to text function, which called [plaintext](http://www.clips.ua.ac.be/pages/pattern-web#plaintext). By default this function removes all HTML tags. For URLs use the existing RegEx.

Comment: Yes, I wanted to try that, but it is not compatible with Python 3.6. So I'm still stuck.